# Web Server load testing

Tags: python, performance, selenium, webserver, load-testing

I am suppose to test web server's load, performance and stress testing. There will be over 100 client machines that will be connecting to it. 
I am using python-selenium webdriver to start a grid. the server is considered as a selenium 'hub' and clients as 'nodes'. This part is working fine till now.

Now the hard part, I need to monitor the server's performance, load and stress from another third party system while the scripts are running.

Is there any possibility if this can work ? I tried using many open sources like funkload, locust, web server stress tool 8. But none of them can monitor the load tests that is swarming dynamically on to the load.

While I was browsing in this site; I came across this project on https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate. Will this be helpful to my project?

Comment: are you looking for a tool to test your application performance? or while performance testing, are you looking for something for profiling your servers?

Comment: 1. I want to know how many clients are connecting to the server's web app. (load test)
2. I want to know what is the performance at each instances while connecting to the server's web app.
If there is any tool supporting this activity, it wud be gr8. I have tried funkload, locust, but I have not tried with Jmeter as I knew it would not interact with my scripts directly.... but I don't think it can make much of a difference here.

Comment: which means you want to do `stress test` you can use Locust. Just write a simple test task to send http request the url you want then from the web console give user and hatch rate. Step by step increase your user until you get a failure and the result. For `load test`, set user/hatch rate what you want and see the respons time of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is a functional tool so it's not a good idea to use it for performance test.

To achieve same you can go with JMETER as it a good open source tool available

still if you want to use selenium then there is some script present to integrate JMeter with selenium. I never tried it but you can try it. 
Refer below link for same:-

**https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler**

http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/performance-test-menu/selenium-load-test-menu/174-use-selenium-webdriver-with-jmeter

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but will this work during my python-selenium scripts that are running ? :)

Comment: Can't say exactly .. but some say that it is not possible in python :- http://qnalist.com/questions/679371/using-python-or-ruby-from-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do with Selenium, but it will take much more resources (especially your time).

I would also recommend to try out the

[LoadComplete from SmartBear](http://smartbear.com/product/loadcomplete/overview/)

It is a very simple and intuitive tool, which lets you run and schedule your tests + send a report with execution results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to conduct the load from 3rd-party web server.

With [PerfMon Metrics Collector](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) plugin you will be able to get server-side health metrics along with the load test results.

See [Getting Started: Scripting with JMeter guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/get-started-scripting-jmeter) and [Learn JMeter in 60 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv7KqxaLZd8) for quick ramp-up on Apache JMeter.

Comment: But this jmeter will work only for virtual users, i believe. I want it to run at a real-time scenario. My scripts will be running on client-side using selenium grid. And what I want is the load of the server-side during the time when these scripts are running ! Is there any solution for that ?